# What are the differences between survival analysis and Poisson regression?

Tags: survival, hazard, poisson-process

I'm working on a classical churn prediction problem using the number of visits of a given user to a site and I thought that Poisson Regression was the right tool for modelling the future engagement of that user. When then I came across a book about survival analysis and Hazard Modelling and I don't know which technique is best.

I don't want to be researching both topics at the same time, so what is best for modelling user engagement using past data and demographics?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Brief and general answer:

- With Poisson regression, the response variable of interest is a **count** ([or possibly a **rate**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression/11183#11183)).
- With Cox regression (or alternative modelling strategies from survival analysis), the response variable is the **time** that has elapsed between some origin and an event of interest. In particular, survival analysis techniques are designed to handle **censoring**.
- Note that, under some assumptions, there is a [link between the two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/does-cox-regression-have-an-underlying-poisson-distribution/8118#8118).

Comment: Is it possible to obtain individual event times resp. when a subject will die?